# How to upload my odoo custom modules on digital ocean?

Tags: python, odoo

Please? I have gotten odoo instance on digital ocean, but just wondering, how do I install custom module on this instance?

Comment: You should have access(ssh) of it then connect it with your local machine and then you can play with it.

Comment: Thanks for yr great answer. But I have been already connected my ssh on instance and run odoo-install.sh script on that. But I dont know how can I add my custom module on this instance. Please?

Comment: If you connect(have access) your machine with your instance. Then hit this command in your terminal `rsync -avzh -e 'ssh -p 4956' path_of_custom_module/custom_module_name instance_username@instance_ip_address:/path_where_to_place_custom_module`